# Is it possible to drop a list of lists from a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm merging multiple data sources together and need to drop certain email addresses from the end result.

I can drop individual strings from my data source:

```
to_drop = ['string 1', '@something.com']
drop_df = pd.DataFrame(db_cust_df[~db_cust_df['email'].str.contains
                       ('|'.join(to_drop))])
```

I can drop a list of strings generated from a dataframe:

```
new_drop_list = db_var_df['email'].tolist()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(drop_df[~drop_cust_df['email'].str.contains
                      ('|'.join(new_drop_list))])
```

How can I drop them all using the same command? Should I just merge the lists together?

```
to_drop = ['string 1', '@something.com']
new_drop_list = db_var_df['email'].tolist()
all_drop = to_drop + new_drop
```

The above merge works great but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: First I see no pandas `merge` or python merge, only a list append. Second, if this works great, what better way do you need?

Comment: if what you want are exact matches, you might consider using the `isin()` functionality (e.g. `db_cust_df.loc[~db_cust_df['email'].isin(to_drop)]`)